# Access properties dynamically with Spring

Tags: java, spring, properties-file, jasypt

I have a Spring application with xml configuration (v4.0.8) where I need to access properties dynamically rather than using `@Value` annotation. I tried using tho methods for this, one of them is using `@ConfigurationProperties` with a Map which gives me all properties in a map, and the other way is using `Environment.getProperty`.

Both methods are getting the properties from the propertySources of the Environment. Unfortunately that contains 5 property sources including system properties, etc, but not my properties files. Therefore I cannot access my properties.

I'm adding my properties using `EncryptablePropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` from jasypt which is a simple implementation of `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` that decrypts encrypted property values. `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` does not add properties to `Environment.propertySources` and I couldn't figure out how can I extend it myself rather than using jasypt implementation and add them to property sources manually.

Two notes:

- `@Value` annotation works fine, because it's not using Environment but goes through configurers during bean creation. There's not problem with that.
- I have a spring boot application where I cold achieve my goal appending to Environment.propertySources by listening to `ApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent` of spring boot and adding my properties to Environment rather than implementing `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer`. But this is only applicable to spring boot applications and my legacy application is not a spring boot app.